# Alchemy API raise error 404

Tags: python, api, python-2.7, alchemyapi

I'm writing a python script to run Alchemy API. I tested the script on text docs and it works well, my problem raised when my input is URL.
Most of the time Alchemy's algorithm response OK but sometimes it's response error 404.
I checked the failed urls on  [Alchemy's demo](http://www.alchemyapi.com/products/demo/alchemylanguage) and the algorithm works well (it means the url isn't broken).

*I looked in old posts and I tried to replace in the url problematic characters "\n", "\r" to "" , none of them worked.

Do you have any suggestions what cause this error?

**UPDATE**
I solved the problem, I used the old api 'Category' instead of 'Taxonomy'.
To extract category instead of using:

```
response = alchemy.category('text', input_data)        
if response['status'] == 'OK':                    
                    category_name = response["category"]
```

**use:**

```
response = alchemy.taxonomy('text', input_data)
if response['status'] == 'OK':
            category_name = response['taxonomy'][0]['label']
```

Comment: Can you show the script w/ some sample URLs that are breaking?

Comment: Don't answer your question in your question, post an answer instead. This is easier for future visitors to your question